# How to stop localhost http://localhost from switching to https://localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localhost

I am writing a web application, and *`http://localhost:3000`* is redirecting to `https://localhost:3000`

This was not happening a month ago when I finished writing two other applications. I went from working with Sinatra to Rails in the past month, although I have worked with Rails prior without any of these issues.

What can I do to stop this forced switching??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due your browser, because you have accessed the app in the HTTPS address, it will automatically switch to the HTTPS version of site.

[Here you have more information for Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/936319), but the solution is to change the settings and set `browser.urlbar.autoFill`  to `false`. Other option could be to clear the History.

Comment: Cheers! That solved it perfectly, deleting my History. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @NAltun It's the way Firefox handles the things, to provide users a more secure web.